# Java mapper recursively with lists

Tags: java, recursion, mapper

I have a mapper method which takes list of entities called **Claim** iterates over them and maps to **CompensationDTO** and adds to list, but entity can contain lists of children entities which type is also **Claim** and those children can also contain list of **Claims**, so to iterate over them all is best to use recursion but i'm not sure how it should be written

```
    private List<CompensationDTO> mapToDTO(List<Claims> claims) {
    List<CompensationsDTO> compensations = new ArrayList<>();
    if (claims.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    for (Claim claim : claims) {
        CompensationDTO compensationDTO = new CompensationDTO();
        compensationDTO.setId(claim.getId());
        compensationDTO.setAmount(claim.getAmount());
        compensationDTO.setType(claim.getType());
        compensations.add(compensationDTO);
        mapToDTO(claim.getChildrenClaims());
    }
    return compensations;
}
```

I understand that the base case should return empty list but i don't know where to put the recursive function call `mapToDTO(claim.getChildrenClaims());`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add compansations.addAll()?:

```
private List<CompensationDTO> mapToDTO(List<Claims> claims) {
List<CompensationsDTO> compensations = new ArrayList<>();
if (claims.isEmpty()) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
for (Claim claim : claims) {
    CompensationDTO compensationDTO = new CompensationDTO();
    compensationDTO.setId(claim.getId());
    compensationDTO.setAmount(claim.getAmount());
    compensationDTO.setType(claim.getType());
    compensations.add(compensationDTO);
    compensations.addAll(mapToDTO(claim.getChildrenClaims()));
}
return compensations;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`mapToDTO` returns `List<CompensationDTO>` and you need to add these elements to your local list.

```
List<CompensationDTO> rec = mapToDTO(claim.getChildrenClaims());
compensations.addAll(rec);
```